# What is the meaning of the butterfly?

Tags: analysis, the-door

In the movie [*The Door*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1223934/) (2009) (German: *Die Tür*), there are repeated occurrences of a butterfly. First of all, *David*'s daughter *Leonie* wants to go catching butterflies when her father doesn't have time for her and when she finally drowns in the pool. Later it is a butterfly that leads *David* to the eponymous door to the past. And at the end of the movie, when future *David* and *Maja* sit at the pool in the past,  we see the butterfly fly away, I think.

So **does the butterfly have any special meaning in the movie, and what could that be?** Given that the movie is about time travel and correcting your past errors, I had to think about the *Butterfly Effect*, both the [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289879/) and the [theoretical concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) it was based on. But that interpretation doesn't hold too strong I think, given that the movie wasn't so much about the future consequences of changes to the past and didn't involve any feedback of past changes to *David*'s or anybody else's future at all.

Comment: Maybe to represent [Butterfly of Death and Rebirth](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ButterflyOfDeathAndRebirth)